# каким образом можно снять видеопоток с вебкамеры на си не используя opencv?

Tags: c, unix

каким образом можно снять видеопоток с вебкамеры на си не используя opencv? В операционной системе unix

Comment: используй gstreamer или ffmpeg

Comment: какой именно уних? солярис ?

Comment: Смотрите исходники `yavta`, если у вас камера непосредственно к хосту подключена (не по сети). И да, это про Linux. У других может быть совсем по-другому, так как это не описано в стандартах типа POSIX.

Comment: вам нужно video for linux, v4l2- документация: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/media/uapi/v4l/v4l2.html, пример https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/media/uapi/v4l/capture.c.html